# How to change model lazyloadness at runtime in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, model, runtime, lazy-loading, propel

I use sfPropelORMPlugin.
Lazyload is ok if I operate on one object per web page. But if there are hundreds I get hundreds of separate DB queries. I'd like to completely disable lazyload or disable it for needed columns on those particularly heavy pages but couldn't find a way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added utility method to peer to be able to set what columns I want to load. Using "pseudo columns" for this type of DB queries. Also I have overridden hydrate() to understand this "markup". All were good until I found out that even though data is hydrated symfony won't understand it and won't let you use it as intended.

PS join was never considered as an option because site is kind of high load.

Answer (score 1):

You should `join` all your relations when you build your query, that way you'll get all data in a single query. Note, you have to use `joinWithRelation()` where `Relation` is a related table name.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on William Durand's answer, perhaps you should also look at the Propel function doSelectjoinAll(), which should pre-load all of the objects related to your relations. Just keep in mind this can be expensive as it relates to memory.

Another technique is to create a custom criteria with your needed joins, then use a manual hydrate technique to add on to your base object. I do this often when the data I need is using aggregates or other columns that are not exactly mapped to objects. There are plenty of hydrate() examples around.